# What is the best way to find a composite?

Tags: java, swt, composite

I have SWT Application (Shell), with a few composite :
A menu bar is inside a composite, also I have a second composite with various elements.

From the action listener of my menu bar, I would like to access one the element of the second composite.

Currently, I find my composite by doing this. Is there a better/simpler way ?

```
Control[] appComposites;
appComposites = parent.getChildren();
Composite remoteFile;
for(int i=0; i<appComposites.length;i++){
    if(appComposites[i].toString().compareTo("RemoteFile {}") == 0){
        remoteFile = (Composite) appComposites[i];
    }
}
//Now I must make another loop inside remoteFile to find the element that I need ...
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `Widget#setData(Object)` to add identification information to `Widget`s.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));

    Listener listener = new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            Widget widget = arg0.widget;

            System.out.println(widget.getData().equals("Button 1");
        }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Button " + i);
        button.setData("Button " + i);

        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

To find out if the `Widget` you are looking at is the one you are searching for, you could use:

```
widget.getData().equals("YOUR IDENTIFIER");
```